# XML Parent node and sub node reading

Tags: c#, xml, parent

XML data

```
<HotelValuedAvailRS xmlns="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages HotelValuedAvailRS.xsd" timeToExpiration="1799971" totalItems="90" echoToken="DummyEchoToken">
    <AuditData>
        <ProcessTime>275</ProcessTime>
        <Timestamp>2014-11-04 11:39:28.253</Timestamp>
        <SchemaRelease>2005/06</SchemaRelease>
        <HydraCoreRelease>2014.07.10.PCI</HydraCoreRelease>
        <HydraEnumerationsRelease>N/A</HydraEnumerationsRelease>
        <MerlinRelease>N/A</MerlinRelease>
    </AuditData>
    <PaginationData currentPage="1" totalPages="5" />
    <ServiceHotel xsi:type="ServiceHotel" availToken="18S4Jo2aVQeZLWqDTnJ3bwbh">
        <ContractList>
            <Contract>
                <Name>ID_B2B_24#BARI</Name>
                <IncomingOffice code="1"></IncomingOffice>
                <Classification code="NOR">Online Price</Classification>
            </Contract>
        </ContractList>
        <DateFrom date="20141228" />
        <DateTo date="20141230" />
        <Currency code="EUR">Euro</Currency>
        <HotelInfo xsi:type="ProductHotel">
            <Code>271</Code>
            <Name>TRYP Palma Bellver Hotel</Name>
            <ImageList>
                <Image>
                    <Type>jpg</Type>
                    <Order>1</Order>
                    <VisualizationOrder>1</VisualizationOrder>
                    <Url>jpg</Url>
                </Image>
                <Image>
                    <Type>jpg</Type>
                    <Order>2</Order>
                    <VisualizationOrder>2</VisualizationOrder>
                    <Url>jpg</Url>
                </Image>
            </ImageList>
        </HotelInfo>
        <HotelInfo xsi:type="ProductHotel">
            <Code>272</Code>
            <Name>Beach Hotel</Name>
            <ImageList>
                <Image>
                    <Type>jpg</Type>
                    <Order>3</Order>
                    <VisualizationOrder>3</VisualizationOrder>
                    <Url>jpg</Url>
                </Image>
                <Image>
                    <Type>jpg</Type>
                    <Order>4</Order>
                    <VisualizationOrder>4</VisualizationOrder>
                    <Url>jpg</Url>
                </Image>
            </ImageList>
        </HotelInfo>
    </ServiceHotel>
</HotelValuedAvailRS>
```

C# Code

```
XmlDocument xdcDocument = new XmlDocument();

xdcDocument.Load(@"E:\\Hotel.xml");

var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdcDocument.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages");

var nl = xdcDocument.SelectNodes("/ns:HotelValuedAvailRS/ns:ServiceHotel/ns:HotelInfo", nsmgr);

foreach (XmlNode xndNode in nl)
{
    string name = xndNode["Name"].InnerText;
    var nl3 = xdcDocument.SelectNodes("/ns:HotelValuedAvailRS/ns:ServiceHotel/ns:HotelInfo/ns:ImageList/ns:Image", nsmgr);
    foreach (XmlNode xndNode3 in nl3)
    {
        string url = xndNode3["Url"].InnerText;
        string order = xndNode3["Order"].InnerText;
    }

}
```

I want to read every details comes under Images list in every hotel info. But my second foreach looping all the images list details without moving to the next hotel info with first foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
var nl3 = xdcDocument.SelectNodes("/ns:HotelValuedAvailRS/ns:ServiceHotel/ns:HotelInfo/ns:ImageList/ns:Image", nsmgr);
```

You request all `.../ns:Image` tags of `xdcDocument`, if you want to select only `ns:Image` of each `xndNode` you must use `SelectNodes` method of the `xndNode`:

```
var nl3 = xndNode.SelectNodes("ns:ImageList/ns:Image", nsmgr);
```

Note the change in the xPath because now we are already in the `ns:HotelInfo` level.

Comment: Hi Luizgrs, If I change the code as you suggest "nl3" not getting any nodes and count show as 0.